# how to pause / wait before return

Tags: java

search of data array produces a panel of click-able results buttons. i need to force the "return recordNumber;" to wait execution until one of the results is clicked so the return can return the appropriate recNo.

every time i try to implement wait() notify() the panel of results buttons fails to populate

```
 public int Search() throws InterruptedException
 {
    JFrame searchFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel();
    searchPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( searchPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
    resultsButton = new JButton[ recordCount ];
    resultsRecNo = new int[ recordCount ];
    searchString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( this, "Search for", "" );
    System.out.println( " searchString = "+searchString );
    resultNo = 0;
    if ( searchString != null && searchString.isEmpty() == false  )
    {
       offset = 0;
       for ( recNo = 0; recNo < recordCount; recNo++ )
       {
           byteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange( dataArray, offset, offset+recordSize );
           tmp = new String( byteArray );
           found = tmp.toLowerCase().contains( searchString.toLowerCase() );
           if ( found == true )
           {
               resultsRecNo[ resultNo ] = recNo + 1;
               resultsButton[ resultNo ] = new JButton( "recNo"+(recNo+1)+" : "+tmp );
// create results buttons
               resultsButton[ resultNo ].addActionListener( new ActionListener() { int getRecNo = resultsRecNo[ resultNo ]; public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { setRecord( getRecNo ); searchFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(searchFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); } } );
               searchPanel.add( resultsButton[ resultNo ] );
               resultNo++;
           }
           offset = offset + recordSize;
       }
       if ( resultNo == 0 )
       {
           resultsButton[ resultNo ] = new JButton( " No Results Found " );
           resultsButton[ resultNo ].addActionListener( new ActionListener() { int getRecNo = 0; public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { setRecord( getRecNo ); searchFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(searchFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); } } );
           searchPanel.add( resultsButton[ resultNo ] );
       }
       JScrollPane resultsScrollPane = new JScrollPane( searchPanel );
       resultsScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       resultsScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
       resultsScrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
       searchFrame.add( resultsScrollPane );
       searchFrame.setSize( frameWidth, frameHeight );
       searchFrame.setVisible( true );
   }
   System.out.println( "getRecNo = "+getRecNo+" : recordNumber = "+recordNumber );
   return recordNumber;
 } /////////////////////////// End Of Method Search()

 public void setRecord( int recno)
 {
    recordNumber = recno;
    System.out.println("setRecord : "+recordNumber);
 }
```

i need return recordNumber to wait until one of the resultsButton(s) gets clicked

Comment: You will want to format your code for better readability if only so we can understand it better. For example, there is no need to have multiple lines of code all placed on a single line.

Comment: If you use an [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) approach your problem is likely to go away.

Comment: As well as use a [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) -- one where the behavior of the GUI (how it reacts to button presses, for instance), depends on the state of key variables.

Comment: Note that you can *still* fix the formatting of your posted code. Your efforts in this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should never block the main thread when dealing with Swing or JavaFX, otherwise the UI freezes and that's bad user experience. Check out this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to find out how to asynchronously handle such tasks on a separate thread.

However in your specific case I believe it's much simpler. If you want to react to the user clicking on some button, it makes a lot more sense to just do whatever you need to do in the listener. Why don't you implement your logic in the listeners rather than try to fit everything in the `search` method? That way, your function would immediately return, and the application would react to the user's click only when it happens, and you wouldn't to freewze anything.

If you really need a synchronous interaction from the user (i.e. an action the user is required to perform before anything can happen), you can do it just like you collected the search string from the user, using a dialog as Hovercraft Full Of Eels pointed out.

As a side-note, here are some tips that would make your code easier to reason about, which will be the first step towards fixing your issues:

- you seem to have a huge amount of global variables. This isn't good, try to have as little state as possible, or even none.
- don't write your listeners on a single line, it's unreadable
- split your methods in smaller methods of about 5-15 lines with good names

Comment: i've been writing code in foxpro2.6 for 30 years. i have no idea what you mean by "as little state as possible" means. goes to show just how new i am to Java.

Comment: So basically your `search` function must create some new buttons, wait for the user to click on one of these buttons, and then return a result? What do you do with the result afterwards?

Comment: Dici, yes you are correct, once the user clicks on a resultsButton the searchPanel gets disposed of and the recordNumber of the clicked-upon resultButton gets used to retrieve data from that record. my issue is that i can't figure out how to pause execution of the "return recordNumber" statement until a resultsButton has been clicked

Comment: As I said,what do you want to do with the outut of this function? The normal workflow for UI programming is to react to user actions when they happen, not to have hard waiting times. In your case, it would mean that your logic to get the record nu,ber and use it should be inside the button listeners.

Comment: i've just delved into Java 6 months ago, i'm starting to come to grips with, but still battling with the whole concept of Object Oriented.

Comment: @WylieQua alright, but you can still answer my question ^^ can your logic fit inside the listeners? Essentially, when the user clicks is when you should trigger the code that uses this user input, you should not have to have a synchronous wait for this.

Comment: the call to this method comes from a Sales form in another class, expecting an int return ... call the search-method, get the returned recordNumber, decide if i need to another search - or - retrieve additional data from recordNumber, and carry-on

Comment: @WylieQua: if this code is supposed to create and display a child window, then you'll want to use a JDialog for the top-level window in the code above, *not* a JFrame. Also, if the user is required to deal with this window before going back to the main program, then the JDialog should be created as a *modal* dialog.

Comment: Yeah Hovercraft Full Of Eels is correct,if you really need the user to do something before your program can continue, use a dialog as you did for the search string. I updated my answerto reflect that. Just note it's not a great thing to force a user to do something with no way of going back, so you should handle te case in which they just decide to close the dialog without doing what they were expected to do.

Comment: @Dici & @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels, ... i think i get the idea, Thanks.